# If we start at some address, how can we determine the addresses that variables occupy throughout a program?

Tags: c++, c

Assuming that the memory locations starts at address 100, consider:

```
int a;
struct{
    char b;
    struct{
        short *c[20];
        char d;
    }e;
}f;
double g;
char *h;
```

I know `a` takes address 100-103, but I'm having trouble determining what happens when you have a structure.  I know the start address for a structure is aligned based on the largest field, and the size of the overall structure is a multiple of the largest field, but I'm having trouble distinguishing between the two when the two structures are nested as above.  Also, if we have a pointer, or an array of numbers as in `short *c[20]` how do we determine the memory taken by this declaration?  If someone can explain the address layout at each line I would greatly appreciate it.  More so, I would appreciate an explanation of why the memory is assigned in this way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is all platform-specific.  There aren't really any general rules.

Comment: This is dependent on the platform you use. Why not try the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: About the only guarantee is that `&f.b == &f`.

Comment: *I know a takes address 100-103* Not necessarily - could be 64 bits. Depends on the platform.

Comment: Keyword: `implementation-defined`

Comment: What if we have a 32-bit architecture?

Comment: @BobJohn It's still implementation defined.

Comment: @BobJohn Actually, I think it's unspecified rather than implementation defined.  (If it is implementation defined, the implementation must document it.  Unspecified means that the implementation doesn't have to document it.)

Comment: @BobJohn: then int might by 16 bit

Answer (score 2):

There's no real rule.  It's up to the compiler.  About all you're guaranteed is that the address of `b` is below the address of `e`, and the address of `c` is below the address of `d`.  And that the addresses of the first elements of each `struct` are the same as the address of the `struct`.  On the other hand, there are no guarantees whatever for the elements outside of any struct.  The compiler may allocate `a`, `f`, `g` and `h` in any way it pleases.

Comment: "first element in struct = address of struct variable" is only true if the struct is a "plain old data" struct.

Comment: What if we are using the ARM architecture?

Comment: @BobJohn Implementations could still do different things.  (In practice, for PODs like these, it's hard to imagine an implementation not adhering to the OS ABI.)]

Answer (score 1):

On x86-16 bit:

```
int a;      // two bytes
struct{
    char b;    // One byte. 
    struct{     // Struct itself is aligned to the size of pointer
        short *c[20];    // pointers may be 2 or 4 bytes depending on compile mode. 
        char d;          // one byte
    }e;
}f;
double g;     // 8 bytes aligned to 8 bytes. 
char *h;    // 2 or 4 bytes.
```

On x86-32 bit:

```
int a;    // four bytes. 
struct{
    char b;   // one byte. 
    struct{   // struct padding to size of pointer. 
        short *c[20];  // pointers are 4 bytes. 
        char d;        // one byte. 
    }e;
}f;
double g;     // 8 bytes, aligned to 8 bytes. 
char *h;      // 4 bytes.
```

On x86-64:

```
int a;      // 4 bytes. 
struct{
    char b;  // One byte.
    struct{   // struct aligned to size of pointer
        short *c[20];   // Pointers are 4 or 8 bytes (typically 8)
        char d;   // One byte.
    }e;
}f;
double g;    // 8 bytes. Aligned to 8 bytes. 
char *h;     // 4 or 8 byte pointer, aligned to size of pointer.
```

In some other architecture, this is perfectly valid:

```
int a;      // 8 bytes
struct{
    char b;   // 4 bytes. 
    struct{   // Struct is not aligned to anything.
        short *c[20];  // Pointers are 8 bytes. 
        char d;       // 4 bytes
    }e;    
}f;
double g;  // 12 bytes, aligned to 4 bytes.  
char *h;   // pointers are 8 bytes.
```

I'll let you do the math for each example to calculate what the actual address is. But like everyone else has said, the layout is entirely up to the compiler, and is not possible to determine without understanding the rules of the particular compiler/architecture of the processor.

Answer (score 0):

Each pointer takes 32 or 64 bits, depending on your platform. An array of 20 elements takes 20 times the size of one such element, and so on.

The extra spaces are taken for alignment reasons. Memories usually can read/write several bytes at the same time, as long as they are in the same word or doubleword. Bytes 100-103 form a doubleword. The next one starts at 104... All this is completely platform-dependant. On some platforms it's even illegal to read a word in a non-word-aligned address.